# How to find TreeNode in TreeView by text?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, treeview

I build a TreeView in a loop. On each iteration I have:

- root node
- previous node name

How can I find the `TreeNode` with specified text if I have access only to root node ?

On step that it twrows exception ("Sequence contains no elements"), tree looks like this:

```
Root
    Folder1
        Folder1.1
    Folder2

    Folder3
```

And I want to add `File1.1.1` as a child to `Folder1.1`.

My code that throws exception.

```
rootNode.Nodes
    .Cast<TreeNode>()
    .Where(x => x.Text == "Folder1.1")
    .Last()
    .Nodes
    .Add("File1.1.1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rootNode.Nodes` will only contains `Folder1~3`. `Folder1.1` is listed under `folder1`'s `Nodes`. So in order to find it, you need get iterate through the entire tree.

```
rooteNode.Flatten()
    .Last(x => x.Text == "Folder1.1")
    .Nodes.Add("File1.1.1");
```

---

```
public static class TreeNodeHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> Flatten(this TreeNode root)
    {
        yield return root;

        foreach(TreeNode node in root.Nodes)
            foreach(var item in Flatten(node))
                yield return item;
    }
}
```